# selection color for a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

If I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that doesn't use the `textLabel` built in to the cell but instead does its own drawing, how can I change the appearance of the `contentView` on selection, like it does automatically for the default text (customizable by setting the `selectedTextColor:`)?

If I change `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, then it only updates after the blue selection background is up, but not while it's animating, like I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just don't subclass UITableViewCell and use the default behavior.
You can fully customize a cell without any subclassing.

Read [this article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) for more details.

Comment: That's in fact what I was doing, but your link still pointed me in the right direction. I needed to change the highlightedTextColor for the UILabel.

Comment: When you talked about "own drawing" I immediately thought subclassing. My bad.
Glad you find a solution

Answer (score 4):

Add this code in your tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath method and just change expected color for UITableViewCell selection style.

```
   //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
   //background selected view 
   UIView *viwSelectedBackgroundView=[[UIView alloc]init];
   viwSelectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:124.0/255.0 green:202.0/255.0 blue:227.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
   cell.selectedBackgroundView=viwSelectedBackgroundView;
   //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have subclassed a UITableViewCell, then you can customise the elements of the cell by overriding the following:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if(highlighted) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
}
```